# How to control a slideshow in libreOffice using command line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, slideshow, libreoffice

How to go to next/previous slide using command line in linux (Ubuntu)?

The command below starts a slideshow, I want to go to next/previous slide using a command.

```
 libreoffice --show /home/aisha/Desktop/sample20.ppt
```

Answer (score 0):

First, start LibreOffice in [listening mode](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/Starting_OpenOffice.org_in_Listening_Mode).  Then enter commands in an interactive python shell.

```
python3
import uno
```

Slide show commands are described at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Working_with_Presentations.

A more complete tutorial is at http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html.  Find the heading "First play with the Python shell to get familiar."

Note: Listening mode is typically slower than normal mode.